# Strange result from isset() on php 5.2.9

Tags: php

Can anyone explain why on PHP 5.2.9 this statement evaluates to true instead of false?

```
echo $value = '2010-01-01 12:30:45';
echo "<br>";
echo isset($value['everythingistrue']) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
```

Comment: Just curious, but why would you even try something like that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're inadvertently accessing a single character (the first) in the string, which is indeed set.

Individual characters can be accessed by numeric offset, so the following will work fine

```
$string = "abc";
echo $string[2], $string[1], $string[0]; // cba
```

In your case, the string `'everythingistrue'` is not a valid string offset and so is converted to a number using the normal string-to-integer rules: so it becomes `0`.  `$value[0]` is set (it is the first character, `2`), so the `isset()` call returns true resulting in your ternary operation evaluating to the string `TRUE`.

For slightly more info, have a peek at [*String access and modification by character*](http://php.net/types.string#language.types.string.substr) in the manual.

Comment: Single-character access uses curly braces in PHP. e.g. `$value{0}` in .this case is `2`

Comment: Interestingly enough `var_dump($value["everythingistrue"])` (keeping `$value` as the OP has defined it) returns `string(1) "2"`.

Comment: As it should be ('2' is the first char), see [also the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr)

Comment: @Brad Christie, there was a time when the `[0]` style (for strings) was considered deprecated/discouraged by some (many!) but officially that is not the case any more. Both square- and curly-brace styles are absolutely acceptable. :)

Answer (score 4):

$value is a string.
You can get characters from it like this $value[0] - first character, $value[4] - fift.

If you try to get the 'blablabla' character, PHP tries to convert it to an Int and it results in 0 - the first character which is "2". Try it - `echo $value['everythingistrue']`

Comment: there's no reason why PHP should try to convert a associative index into a numeric one, as php arrays handle associative keys as well

Comment: @tacone, well, yes, but $value variable ISN'T an array.

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump($value['everythingistrue'])` may clear up your doubts